# MFC/BCGP: Update CEditView's tab label without changing the contents of the CEditView?

Tags: mfc, bcg

When I have a SDI Document-View MFC application which uses `CBCGPTabView` as the main view, one of the tabs is a `CEditView`.  If I send a custom message to the `CBCGPTabView` derived class and use `GetTabControl().SetTabLabel()` it not only changes the tab label but contents of the `CEditView`.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: What's the value of your custom message?

Comment: based on WM_APP

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I have for now:

```
  // hack to work around ceditview getting its window contents changed
  CView* pview=GetView(tabi);
  if (pview->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEditView))) {
    CString strexistingtext;
    pview->GetWindowText(strexistingtext);
    // change label
    tabctrl.SetTabLabel(tabi, strlabel);
    // put back text
    pview->SetWindowText(strexistingtext);
  }
  else {
    // change label
    tabctrl.SetTabLabel(tabi, strlabel);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to override

```
virtual CString CBCGPMDIChildWnd::GetFrameText() const
```

And put / set there what you need.